# Website with SSL Certificate

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, ssl-certificate, security

The website I currently created isn't using a ssl cert. If I decide to buy and use a ssl cert for my website do I need to change any code on my website? My website is written in html, php and it has a mysql backend.

Or can I just purchase a new ssl cert and not change any code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The SSL connection is handled by the web server, the code running on top of it has nothing much to do with it. Your code should continue to run as is if the web server is configured sensibly. If you are hardcoding links using `http://...` somewhere or are otherwise somehow depending on the presence or absence of HTTP/HTTPS in your code, you may need to change these specific parts.

Comment: You answered my question perfetly. Thanks!